# Copy All Visible(Formatted Text) from Excel to Outlook using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Copy All Visible(Formatted Text) from Excel to Outlook using VBA?

Please find below code to send email through outlook. However, I want to send the email with a selection that I have copied below using code. 
I do not wish to create a Table as HTML but instead just copy all visible?

```
Sub EmailRep()


Dim Mailbody As Range

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim Outlook As Outlook.Application
Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim outmail As MailItem
Set outmail = Outlook.CreateItem(0)

Set Mailbody = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A1:F30")
Mailbody.Copy

With outmail

.To = "abc@xyz.com"
.Subject = "All Open"
.Body = "This is Test Email"
.Display
.Send
End With


Set Outlook = Nothing
Set outmail = Nothing
Set Mailbody = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correct change your line of :

```
Set Mailbody = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A1:F30")
```

To

```
Set Mailbody = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("A1:F30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Although in your code you are not putting the range into the body of the email. At first thought you pasted the range by hand but then I noticed you have `.Send` in code which would send the email before you got a chance to paste.

Either way the above will copy only the visible range.

If you are interested in a quick way to send your range in an email without the need to copy the below is pretty short and sweet:

```
Sub EmailRep()
With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Range("A1:F30").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
    .Introduction = "This is Test Email"
    .Item.To = "abc@xyz.com"
    .Item.Subject = "All Open"
    .Item.Send
End With

ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the Code it worked perfectly but If you don't mind could you tell me what exactly is wrong with my CODE. I would like to know where I am wrong

Comment: @Shoaibkhanz What do you mean? AS the first lines of my answer explain your range selection did not filter for only the visible cells, by using the specialcells method of the range object, You are able to get only the visible cells in the range. Besides that your code only copied the range to the windows clipboard you never did anything (at least in your code) with the copied range afterwards.

Comment: Although, I struggled to understand every bit of your code initially. But I do understand it now thanks, sorry for late reply.